# Apps will not open - Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 23.04

I am trying to open apps on my HP 15S-FQ0XXX (laptop) which I have just installed. I’m only able to open apps like terminal and settings. Software Centre and Firefox (etc) are not opening. Only thing I’ve done is installed, rebooted as it said there were a few things that needed to be updated (I do not know what, but maybe Python) and then tried to open apps. Here’s everything about my laptop I can get from settings:

```
Hardware: HP Laptop 15s-fq0xxx (silver)
Firmware: F.26
Memory (RAM): 4.0 GIB
Processor: Intel Celeron N4120 x 4
Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2)
Disk Capacity: 128 GB
OS Name: Ubuntu 23.04
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME Version: N/A
Windowing System: Wayland
Kernel: Linux 6.2.0-20-generic
```

I still have my bootable USB, by the way!

Comment: You can run a check for new software again: `sudo apt update`, followed by `sudo apt list --upgradable`. When that shows a list of upgradable software, run: `sudo apt upgrade`. After that is finished reboot, and retry these steps until  no new software/updates are shown.

Comment: 4GiB is not a lot of RAM these days.

Comment: Can you type `inxi -Fxz` in a terminal and copy the output into your question? You can install `inxi` with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install inxi`

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 works on my old (2014) laptop with 4GiB, and Firefox (snap package) works. Sometimes it is necessary to launch it twice.

Comment: I consulted with a friend, given your legacy machine, uninstall the snap version of Firefox and reinstall directly from the command line.

Comment: Don't guess about what the problem *might* be. Immediately after a failed attempt to launch an application, review your logs: `journalctl -xe` and `tail /var/log/syslog`. Note that log entries are timestamped, so you can easily tell which occurred at the time of failure. Copy the complete log entry text and paste them into your question above.

Comment: Did you change your python version?